# Can I spy on an object rather than an object method?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I know that I can use spy like below to track the number of times a function has been called, when I have a reference to the object on which it is a method.

```
jest.spyOn(myObj, 'myFunc')
```

But what do I do when I have a reference to the function that I want to use? `jest.spyOn(myFunc)` does not work

To clarify, I want to use the real implementation of the function. I just want to be able to see how many times it has been called and with which arguments.

When I try to see those things on an ordinary function I get:

```
  expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Here is (most of) the actual test:

```
  it('should set createScrollContextImmediately when result is above the maximum return limit', async () => {
    // Arrange
    ...
    // Act
    await fetch(imageID, { size: maxSizePerScroll }, ids, { createScrollContextImmediately: false });
    // Assert
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(imageID, { size: maxSizePerScroll }, ids, { createScrollContextImmediately: false });
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(imageID, { size: maxSizePerScroll }, ids, { createScrollContextImmediately: true });
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? If you're dealing with a single function, inject a `jest.fn()` instead of the real implementation; you don't need to spy on anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added more context at the end of the post

Comment: You could use [`jest.fn().mockImplementation(...)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) but generally you should have either a test double *or* a real implementation - this half-way house is a bit of a smell. Hence the request for context, *why* do you want that? What are you actually testing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Yeah, unfortunately, I think that I still don't understand how to write good tests

Comment: sadly that is not uncommon! Here's a post of use of test doubles generally: https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/the-test-double-rule-of-thumb/

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added the actual test. Hopefully that can help you help me ^_^

Comment: If the thing you're calling is fetch you *definitely* don't want to be calling through to the real implementation, unit tests shouldn't hit the actual network. Ideally you'd have a facade to isolate your code from the real interface, then mock that facade (don't mock what you don't own) but either way if you want to have different values coming back at different times from a function that returns promises, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1.** You can mock the `fetch` function using `jest.mock` with the real implementation. And, we can add a spy in the implementation. You can make assertions for that spy.

E.g.

`fetch.ts`:

```js
export async function fetch(name) {
  return 'real implementation';
}
```

`fetch.test.ts`:

```js
import { fetch } from './fetch';

const fetchSpy = jest.fn();

jest.mock('./fetch', () => {
  const { fetch } = jest.requireActual('./fetch');
  const fetchWithSpy = jest.fn().mockImplementation((...args) => {
    fetchSpy(...args);
    return fetch(...args);
  });
  return {
    fetch: fetchWithSpy,
  };
});

describe('65266282', () => {
  it('should set createScrollContextImmediately when result is above the maximum return limit', async () => {
    const actual = await fetch('teresa teng');
    expect(actual).toBe('real implementation');
    expect(fetchSpy).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
    expect(fetchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
PASS  examples/65266282/fetch.test.ts
  65266282
    ✓ should set createScrollContextImmediately when result is above the maximum return limit (8 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.216 s
```

**Option 2.** You can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to create a proxy for your `fetch` function.

> The Proxy object enables you to create a proxy for another object, which can intercept and redefine fundamental operations for that object.

`fetch-v2.test.ts`:

```js
import { fetch } from './fetch';

const fetchSpy = jest.fn();
const fetchProxy = new Proxy(fetch, {
  apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
    fetchSpy.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
    return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
  },
});

describe('65266282', () => {
  it('should set createScrollContextImmediately when result is above the maximum return limit', async () => {
    const actual1 = await fetchProxy('teresa teng');
    expect(actual1).toBe('real implementation');
    const actual2 = await fetchProxy('best singer');
    expect(actual2).toBe('real implementation');
    expect(fetchSpy).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
    expect(fetchSpy).toBeCalledWith('best singer');
    expect(fetchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65266282/fetch-v2.test.ts
  65266282
    ✓ should set createScrollContextImmediately when result is above the maximum return limit (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.484 s
```

The two methods are essentially the same. The core idea is to use proxy, interceptor, high order function